# script command failing

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to use `script` command in my script to record my session. But whenever I start it, it gets terminated at the same instant.

```
home@ubuntu-box:~$  script /tmp/myfile.txt
Script started, file is /tmp/myfile.txt

Script done, file is /tmp/myfile.txt
home@ubuntu-box:~$
```

Could someone please help me, how can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the full content of the script? Post it on pastebin.com or something.

Comment: Can you start `script` with output to different file  ?  Try `~/myfile.txt` . Also, what is the permissions on `/tmp` directory ?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju `script` command is used to record a terminal session to a file, it's not an actual command line script.  See [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/use-unix-linux-script-command-record-your-command-line-i-o)

Comment: @Serg same results. It started and done. Someone suggested me to switch shell and it worked. I changed to zsh shell.

Comment: That is very odd, because `script` should work with any shell